# How do I render react files using python routes?

Tags: python, reactjs

Is it possible to render react files using python routes? I have tried to pip install python-react-v8 but I get a sea of errors anytime I try... Can someone please point me in the right direction?

```
@Auth.route('/login', methods=['GET'])
def login():
    #data = {'username':'bob', 'password':'peepee123'}
    #session['token'] = 'jsdkfkj934ujeklfjdlndsflds'
      # return jsonify(session['token'] ) 
         # return make_response('Could Not verify!', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm = "Login Required"'})'''
               #  return jsonfiy({'token': token.decode('UTF-8')})
                  # auth = request.authorization

  #  if auth and auth.password == 'password':
   #     token = jwt.encode({'user': auth.username}, app.config['SECRET_KEY'])




    return('index.js')
```

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Comment: Just posted one.

Comment: There's a lot of random comments in there. What's the *problem* with it?

Comment: Did you try looking into the quick-start of the docs? https://python-react-v8.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#quick-start

Comment: I have no idea how to render that react file using a python route... Do I need to import react in my python? Do I need to be more specific where my index.js is located in my files?

Comment: Yes I looked at the docs, but when I tried pip installing python-react-v8 I got a sea of errors for some reason....

Comment: But what you've shown *isn't* the installation, or any error relating to it. How do you expect people to help with a problem they know nothing about?